# How to cut string from string has "abc" in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem. My string has format `"abc"`, it has **""**. Now i want to get only `abc` from `"abc"` ( mean remove "" from string and get only abc). How can i do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your string starting with an " and the last character is " ?

Comment: @incmiko: yes, correct.

Comment: I wrote my answer check it

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *abc = [@"\"abc\"" stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *input = @"\"abc\"";
        NSArray *elements = [input componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""];
        if ([elements count] > 0) {
            NSString *element = [elements objectAtIndex:1];
            NSLog(@"count=%lu element='%@'", [elements count], element);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

$ clang -o strsep strsep.m -framework Foundation
$ ./strsep
2013-10-07 11:42:44.274 strsep[34292:707] count=3 element='abc'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[String replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [String length])];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in function that enables you to replace all occurrences of a substring with another one - if that another one is set to be an empty string (**@""**) it will effectively delete all occurrences of he substring. Your example:

```
NSString * yourNewString = [yourOldString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace occurrences of " with an empty space.

```
NSString *some = @"\"abc\"";
NSLog(@"%@",some);
NSString *newString = [some stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@",newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a method for you, this will work perfectly: (if your last character is " )

```
- (NSString*) getTheString:(NSString*) yourString{
    NSString* answerString = [[NSString alloc]init];

    int substrinFrom = 0;
    for (NSInteger charIdx=0; charIdx<[yourString length]; charIdx++){

        if ( '"' == [yourString characterAtIndex:charIdx]) {
            substrinFrom = charIdx;
            NSLog(@"%i",substrinFrom);
            break;
        }
    }
    answerString = [yourString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(substrinFrom+1, [yourString length] - substrinFrom -2 )];

    return answerString;

}
```

to test it:

```
NSString* test = [self getTheString:@"\"Hello this is a test string, and it will work\""];
NSLog(@"%@",test);
```